# Error: "Get-ADUser : The operation returned because the timeout limit was exceeded."

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-5.0

I am working on creating a script to copy specific information from an existing AD User into a new account.  The script is giving me 3 errors, the third one i know is because the script fails before it gets to that section.

```
Get-ADUser : The operation returned because the timeout limit was exceeded.
At line:115 char:14
+ $New_Path = (Get-ADUser ($UsernameCopy.Text)).DistinguishedName -repl ...
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationTimeout: (cnelsontest:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], TimeoutException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.TimeoutException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

New-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command 
again.
At line:155 char:35
+ New-ADUser -Name $New_DisplayName @params
+                                   ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'cnelsontest1' under: 'DC=azcorrections,DC=local'.
At line:159 char:29
+                             Add-ADGroupMember -Members $Username.Text
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cnelsontest1:ADPrincipal) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

[Full Script link](https://pastebin.com/qWzKq0Bk)

Here is the line the first error refers to:

`$New_Path = (Get-ADUser ($UsernameCopy.Text)).DistinguishedName -replace '^.*?,\s*(?=ou=)', ''`

I have a feeling the second error message is caused by the first error, and the third error message is because it doesn't complete the New-ADUser command.

I'm running PSVersion 5.1.150

Edit: Can someone assist me in figuring out what the error messages mean as well as how to fix it?

Comment: Flagged as "Unclear what you're asking"

Comment: Don't forget to ask your question.

Comment: Edited to ask a question

Comment: The error means exactly what it says. The request to the DC is taking too long to actually return data so it gives up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into three different errors being thrown:

1. > Get-ADUser : The operation returned because the timeout limit was exceeded.

This one is obvious. You have a timeout on the AD server and it was exceeded before it found a result.  You can adjust the timeout or deal with no returns.

2. > New-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

You provided a bad (empty) path argument.

3. > Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'cnelsontest1' under: 'DC=azcorrections,DC=local'.

The object `cnelsontest1` doesn't exist in the `DC=azcorrections,DC=local` path.

Comment: To summarize, "Read error descriptions first, they really mean it".

Comment: @Vesper Basically.  I understand `ErrorRecord`'s can be difficult to learn at first, they're worth the effort.

Comment: Ya, i just wanted to ensure i wasn't missing anything with the error messages.  it's worked properly since i made this post.  Thank you for the clarifications.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - how do you extend the timeout for this type of command, I'm not seeing any flags for that?

Comment: @Abraxas it's on the AD side

Comment: `1. You can adjust the timeout or deal with no returns.`   Please can you tell us how to adjust the timeout?  What is the syntax for this?